# extra options not allowed for clipping path command

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

using the below code, I encountered `extra options not allowed for clipping path command` error, How can I solve it?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
    \clip[draw=black,postaction={fill=black, draw=white, line width=6mm}] (58,77) rectangle +(9,9);
    \clip[postaction={fill=black, line width=6mm}] (61,80) rectangle +(3,3);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you need to separate the clipping and the drawing commands or swap places in postaction.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `preaction`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
    \path[preaction={clip},draw=black,postaction={fill=black, draw=white, line width=6mm}] (58,77) rectangle +(9,9);
    \clip[postaction={fill=black, line width=6mm}] (61,80) rectangle +(3,3);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If `preaction` is occupied, remember that `preaction` can be nested. For example

```
preaction={preaction={scale=1.1},rotate=10}
```